# Contact us gem route conflict - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ContactUs::Contacts#new`, using this gem https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us .

The error: `No route matches {:controller=>"contact_us/pages", :action=>"home"}`

Where the error is occurring:

```
.col-xs-8
            %ul
                %li
                    = link_to "Home", :controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'
                %li
                    = link_to "About", :controller => 'pages', :action => 'about'
                %li
```

My routes:

```
devise_for :users
resources :available_times

root :to => "pages#home"

get 'about' => 'pages#about'
get 'pricing' => 'pages#pricing'

get 'users/my-bookings' => 'available_times#index'
get 'users/x34' => 'available_times#create'
get 'users/test_func/:id/:time' => 'available_times#test_func'
```

Gem routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts,
    :controller => 'contact_us/contacts',
    :only       => [:new, :create]
  get '/contact-us' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a scoping issue. The view is rendered in the `contact_us` scope and calling a controller in that scope will have it look for it in `contact_us/` rather than the entire app. I'm no big fan of using the `:controller => 'pages', :action => 'home'` for routes generation directly, try and use the path helper instead. It will probably work better.

```
= link_to "Home", root_path
= link_to "About", about_path
```

In routes:

```
get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about
```